# Encrypt a string to match length of original string

Tags: c#, string, encryption

I need a simple c# algorithm that will take a string of x characters and 'encrypt' it to another string of also x characters. It doesn't have to be secure, but it shouldn't be possible to reconstruct the original string by simply looking at the the encrypted string. For instance, if I enter "hello", I should get something like "x=w3q". It shouldn't simply map each character to something else, but it doesn't have to be much more complicated than that. It needs to be symmetrical, so I need to be able to construct "hello" from "x=w3q".

So far I've tried RijndaelManaged and RSA encryption, but the encrypted string is a lot longer than the original string.

Any ideas?

Comment: ROT13 is always an option! :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to encrypt a "human readable" string to another "human readable" string. You convert `hello` to `x=w3q`, but in truth encryption normally converts from bytes to bytes, so it would convert `hello` (UTF8) to some 5 random unshowable bytes. For this reason often you base64 the encrypted string, to make it readable again... but base64 enlarges the string.

Comment: ROT13 can be easily reconstructed by simply looking at it.

Comment: This is an active field of study called "Format Preserving Encryption" or FPE (because we love three letter acronyms).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes This is quite interesting... is there anything pre-done in c/c#/java?

Comment: @xanatos Possibly, but not in any popular libraries. FPE is hard to get right, especially in any practical sense (there are different schemes, and not all of them are very efficient for specific inputs, so it's hard to create a generic one). It's talked about in Crypto I from prof Boneh at Coursera).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start off using a ROT13 algorithm and then change the offset based on the previous character.

Example: "hello"

ROT13 for 'h' --> 'u'

Since U is the 21st letter of the alphabet, you would next use ROT21:

ROT8 for 'e' --> 'z'

And so on.

This would not only keep the length intact but could also handle extra characters as long as you add them to an alphabet.

I apologise if this isn't clear enough for now, I'm on my phone.

**EDIT:**

Here's some code, this will make a lot more sense:

```
    static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static String encrypt(String originalString)
{
    String returnString = "";
    int shift = alphabet.Length / 2; 

    foreach (char c in originalString)
    {
         int nextIndex = alphabet.IndexOf(c) + shift;

         if (nextIndex > alphabet.Length)
            nextIndex = nextIndex - alphabet.Length;

         returnString += alphabet[nextIndex];
         shift = alphabet.IndexOf(alphabet[nextIndex]);
    }

    return returnString;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedString)
{        
    String returnString = "";
    int shift = alphabet.Length / 2; 

    foreach (char c in encryptedString)
    {
        int nextIndex = alphabet.IndexOf(c) - shift;

         if (nextIndex < 0)
            nextIndex = alphabet.Length + nextIndex; // nextIndex is negative so we are decreasing regardless

        returnString += alphabet[nextIndex];
        shift = alphabet.IndexOf(c);
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

The alphabet can be expanded as much as you want. It's not safe, but it's simple and it can't be deciphered easily just by looking at it.

Comment: Made a mistake here, I should use the 'encrypted' character to change the offset, not the original one, otherwise it's impossible to recover the original text.

Comment: "It shouldn't simply map each character to something else, but it doesn't have to be much more complicated than that." OK, but this scheme is only slightly better than ROT13 - it is only stronger in case an attacker doesn't know the scheme (if you brute force the key you can do frequency analysis without any problem).

Comment: ROTX etc. also doesn't "encrypt" spaces, digits etc. so you may want to expand your alphabet.

Comment: Thanks, but what if there are spaces or numbers in the text?

Comment: I just expanded the alphabet: `static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890- "`

Comment: Great, I also added caps now.

Comment: BUG??  This email address: "sage_wieser@cox.net" failed to encrypt when I set the alphabet string to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@._-" 

I was able to get it (along with 500 other test email addresses) to work by changing this line: 

`if (nextIndex > alphabet.Length)`

to:

`if (nextIndex >= alphabet.Length)`

Comment: @DevonTaig that worked like a charm. I had problems of "Array out of index" but this fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a well known (classical) cipher here's an implementation of Vigenère.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Simple object oriented implementation of the classical Vigenère cipher.
 * Note that Vigenère is - of course - not considered secure anymore.
 *
 * @author maartenb
 */

public class Vigenère {
    private static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final int LA = ALPHABET.length();

    /**
     * Flags to be used for the Vigenère cipher.
     */
    public enum Flag {
        /**
         * Do not encrypt/decrypt space characters but leave them in the same
         * position.
         */
        SKIP_SPACE;
    }

    private enum State {
        INSTANTIATED, INITIALIZED;
    }

    private enum Operation {
        ENCRYPT, DECRYPT;

        public int direction() {
            switch (this) {
            case ENCRYPT:
                return 1;
            case DECRYPT:
                return -1;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }
    }

    private State state = State.INSTANTIATED;
    private String key;
    private int lk;
    private Set<Flag> flags;

    /**
     * Initializes the cipher with the given key.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the key that can only use the characters in the alphabet
     * @param flags
     *            option flag parameters
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the key contains invalid characters
     */
    public void init(final String key, final Set<Flag> flags) {
        if (key == null || key.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key null or empty");
        }

        this.lk = key.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.lk; i++) {
            if (ALPHABET.indexOf(key.codePointAt(i)) == -1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key character nat index "
                        + i + " not in alphabet");
            }
        }
        this.key = key;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.state = State.INITIALIZED;
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts the plaintext using the key set during initialization.
     *
     * @param plaintext
     *            the plaintext, using the characters in the alphabet
     * @return the ciphertext
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *             if the cipher wasn't initialized
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the plaintext contains characters not in the alphabet
     */
    public String encrypt(final String plaintext) {
        if (this.state != State.INITIALIZED) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not initialized");
        }

        return crypt(plaintext, Operation.ENCRYPT);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts the ciphertext using the key set during initialization.
     *
     * @param ciphertext
     *            the ciphertext, using the characters in the alphabet
     * @return the plaintext
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *             if the cipher wasn't initialized
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the ciphertext contains characters not in the alphabet
     */
    public String decrypt(final String ciphertext) {
        if (this.state != State.INITIALIZED) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not initialized");
        }

        return crypt(ciphertext, Operation.DECRYPT);
    }

    private String crypt(final String in, final Operation op)
            throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {

        final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in.length());

        // legend: c = character, k = key, o = offset, in = input, out = output
        int skipped = 0;
        for (int ino = 0; ino < in.length(); ino++) {
            // get character (code point in Unicode)
            final int inc = in.codePointAt(ino);
            // skip space, if configured
            if (inc == ' ' && this.flags.contains(Flag.SKIP_SPACE)) {
                out.appendCodePoint(' ');
                skipped++;
                continue;
            }
            // get matching key character
            final int kc = this.key.codePointAt(mod(ino - skipped, this.lk));
            final int kco = ALPHABET.indexOf(kc);
            final int inco = ALPHABET.indexOf(inc);
            if (inco == -1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Invalid character at offset " + ino);
            }

            // the main calculation
            final int outco = mod(inco + op.direction() * kco, LA);
            final int outc = ALPHABET.codePointAt(outco);
            out.appendCodePoint(outc);
        }
        return out.toString();
    }

    private static int mod(final int x, final int n) {
        // note that % is the remainder operation in Java
        // so it doesn't handle negative values correctly
        return (x % n + n) % n;
    }

    /**
     * Main method for testing purposes only.
     *
     * @param args
     *            ignored
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // example taken from Wikipedia page on Vigenère
        final Vigenère vigenere = new Vigenère();
        vigenere.init("LEMON", EnumSet.of(Vigenère.Flag.SKIP_SPACE));
        final String ct = vigenere.encrypt("ATTACK AT DAWN");
        System.out.println(ct);
        final String pt = vigenere.decrypt(ct);
        System.out.println(pt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I admit, I just felt like programming it.

Answer (score 1):

You can map to different characters based on the index of the character, which just makes it less obvious.

```
private static readonly int[] charOffsets = new[]{30,26,39,...};

private static char EncryptChar(char c, int index)
{
    return (char)(c + charOffests[index % charOffsets.Length]);
}

private static char DecryptChar(char c, int index)
{
    return (char)(c - charOffests[index % charOffsets.Length]);
}

public static string Encrypt(string str)
{
    return new string(str.Select((c, i) => EncryptChar(c, i)));
}

public static string Decrypt(string str)
{
    return new string(str.Select((c, i) => DecryptChar(c, i)));
}
```

You can tweak with it a little if you only want alphabetic characters, etc. But you get the idea, I hope.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for something built in, but guess it's too simple!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a classical cipher, such as [Vigenère](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).  If you are prepared to accept bytes, rather than readable characters, then [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) is a more modern alternative.

Both Vigenère and RC4 are insecure and not safe for commercial grade encryption. For that you need AES. For the same output length, you could try AES in CTR mode, though you will need to send the key and nonce separately in that case.

Comment: It is much more complex... what the questioner sees as characters are unicode chars, so 2 bytes. Even using utf8, while 'a' is 1 byte, 'è' is two bytes...

Comment: I'm with you with regards to the Vigenère cipher, but the description of RC4 and AES completely skips over encoding and decoding issues and it doesn't adequately explain about the issues around the nonce, which is vital for CTR.